# Почему есть разница в полученных данных на windows и linux после получения ответа с сервера

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, decode, brotli

После выполнения запроса в полученном ответе на windows и на linux разные значения.
На windows:

```
b'results: [{Elems: [,…], ID: 2, Name: ...
```

На linux:

```
 b'\xa5\xff\xff\x00\x00\xa8\xaa\x
```

Это из-за различия кодеков при декодировке? Как это обойти или исправить?

Код программы:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import requests as r

headers = {
    'authority': '1xbjw.world',
    'method': 'GET',
    'path': '/results/getmain?date=2019-06-13&showAll=true',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'refer': 'https://1xbjw.world/ru/results/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }

rq = r.get('https://1xhlj.world/results/getmain?date=2019-06-13&showAll=true', headers=headers)

print(rq)
data = rq.content.decode('utf-8')

print(data[:50])

with open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: Начните с выкидывания всех http-заголовков, назначение которых вам неизвестно. Не нужно всё бездумно копипастить из браузера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если выдать заголовки ответа, то среди них обнаружится такой:

```
'Content-Encoding': 'br'
```

Это значит, что сервер послал контент сжатым с помощью алгоритма brotli (ты сообщил серверу в запросе, что умеешь обходиться с ним, послав `br` в заголовке `Accept-Encoding`). Контент сначала нужно распаковать<sup>1</sup>:

```
import brotli
try:
    decompressed = brotli.decompress(rq.content)
except brotli.error:  # content seems to be decompressed
    decompressed = rq.content
```

Затем декодировать. Хороший стиль - сначала пробовать ту кодировку, которую шлет сервер в заголовке `Content-Type`, потом пробовать угадать кодировку с помощью `chardet`, ну и уж если ничего не помогает, брать хардкодом (хотя я бы не стал в этом месте продолжать гадать и просто кинул исключение):

```
data = decompressed.decode(rq.encoding or rq.apparent_encoding or 'utf-8')
```

В данном случае сервер правильный и шлет кодировку в заголовке (`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`), так что должно работать на обеих ОС.

P.S. почему код работает на windows, не знаю, не работаю с этой ОС. Может, кто-то сведущий подскажет?

---

<sup>1</sup> Если импорт кидает исключение, установи `brotlipy`: `pip install brotlipy`

Comment: brotli.error: BrotliDecompress failed - выдаёт такую ошибку

Comment: А на какой ОС, linux или windows?

Comment: операционная система linux

Comment: Хм, тогда предложение такое - пробовать распаковать в `try`-блоке, при исключении работать с контентом как обычно. Я дополнил код в ответе, попробуй его.

Comment: спасибо, заработало. Вышло так, что запрос на определённые дни выдаёт нормальный ответ. То есть в запросе была проставлена сегодняшняя дата, и ответ был сжатым. Я попытался сделать запрос на прошлые даты, вышел нормальный ответ.